# Iteration over std::set does not end

Tags: c++

Today i was trying to print elements of a set , Which went into an infinite loop .
When i tried to fetch the size of set , it returned me correct value which was 8.

the code was like this

```
     std::cout << "size of set is " << myset.size();
     for(it=myset.begin();it!=myset.end();it++)
     std::cout << "value is : " << *it;
```

iterator it was declared above before fetching the size . And one of the interesting fact was that one of the expected element was missing from set while printing it.

I know i would appear mad to you or making some silly mistake but my concern is that is it 
possible that myset.end() points to some random place ? But even though so why was it repeating the elements from set while printing and not crashing

Comment: The problem lies in the code you're not showing us.

Comment: my concern is can end() function go haywire ... i have never seen it 
second thing is why is it giving the size as 8 and i have the for loop just below the statement where i printed size. How can it go so wrong ?

Comment: Please post a *complete*, *minimal* sample program that demonstrates your error. A *complete* program is one which we can copy-paste and compile. A *minimal* program contains no lines that are unrelated to your problem. I know it seems difficult to produce one, but it is valuable. We will be better able to solve your problem with one. Also, you may solve it on your own while producing the minimal sample. See http://sscce.org/.

Comment: @Rob: you can just reference the online definition for a [short, self-contained, compilable example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

The `.end()` iterator returned by all STL containers points to one-past-the-end of the container, and dereferencing it (`*iterator`) results in undefined behavior.

Your for loop will not dereference `.end()` though as it stops when your iterator equals .end(), so this should not be a problem in the code you've posted.  You probably  had a different mistake in your other code earlier.

Comment: Yes deferencing it leads to segmentation fault genrally . But mine case is differnt . I am not getting any error except it going in for loop infinitely with size being displayed as 8 :(

Comment: The loop you've posted won't display the size, your size line is above the loop.  Post your real code so we can find the real error :)

Comment: yeah loop will only print me the element in set . Since it went in infite loop , i printed the size to check what is the size being displayed for set . The actual code is a lengthy one and a confidential one which i guess will be hard for me to replicate here

Comment: I don't know what to tell you.  Your errors in your real code, and we can't debug it without at least seeing an example that reproduces the problem.  The segment that you posted won't reproduce the problem at all.  Make a small segment of code that reproduces your problem and post it and we can tell you whatever language feature/syntax is confusing you.

Comment: ok .. i will post it tomorrow the real segment with traces showing size as 8 and going in infinite loop .... Regards